# Change session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime in Docker php-apache

Tags: php, docker, session

I want to increase the session lifetime in php.ini.
Unfortunatelly I cannot use ini_set in php script itself, due to other circumstances like using some compozer stuff.

Anyway, usually on a root server I would simply change those settings in the native php.ini.
But inside the container, build by image php:7.4-apache, I cannot find the right place to do it.

Does anyone know which php.ini is used inside the container?

I tried this in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -i "s/session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440/session.gc_maxlifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production
RUN sed -i "s/session.cookie_lifetime = 0/session.cookie_lifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production

RUN sed -i "s/session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440/session.gc_maxlifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
RUN sed -i "s/session.cookie_lifetime = 0/session.cookie_lifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
```

The change is there in the container, but when I have a look in my phpinfo(), I can see, that still the default session time of 1440 is set for session.gc_maxlifetime.

[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNoY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you took a look at `Loaded Configuration File` section in phpinfo() output you would probably see an empty value there which means no php.ini was loaded.
So, my guess you need to create the config file firstly and then you will be able to modify its values.

Here is how your Dockerfile should look like:

```
...
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440/session.gc_maxlifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/session.cookie_lifetime = 0/session.cookie_lifetime = 604800/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
...
```